# Why I can't assign string data to my nsuserdefaults in Swift?

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, swifty-json

I have a call to my webservice and it fetches 3 string values, I want to store them for good, so I thought about using `nsuserdefaults`. This is my code for that:

```
var username = json["id"]
var googleUserId = json["g_username"]
var facebookUserId = json["f_username"]

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(username, forKey: "username")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(googleUserId, forKey: "googleUserId")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(facebookUserId, forKey: "facebookUserId")


NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

The error I'm getting says:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'JSON' to expected argument type 'AnyObject?'
```

What's the problem here?

==== EDIT

sorry for not mentioning that before - the json variable comes from alamofire response, this is how it looks in my code:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://mywebservice", parameters: par) .response { 
(request, response, data, error) in 
if(error == nil){
var json = JSON(data: data!)
```

Comment: You didn't show us how `json` is declared, what's its type?

Comment: @TimVermeulen please see my edit, sorry for not mentioning it before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using SwiftyJSON, so you should also use SwiftyJSON's features. :)

There's no need to "downcast" dictionary results with SwiftyJSON, it's already done!

Each SwiftyJSON object has optional getters and non-optional getters.

You have a field with a string as a result? Use `.string`:

```
if let username = json["id"].string {
    defaults.setObject(username, forKey: "username")
}
```

For integers it would be `.int`, for arrays it is `.array`, etc.

There's also the non-optional getters, they have the word "Value" added to the property:

```
let username = json["id"].stringValue
defaults.setObject(username, forKey: "username")
```

But warning! A non-optional getter will assume that the value is here and force-unwrap, so if it's nil, it will crash: `json["id"].stringValue` is the same as `json["id"].string!`.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
var username = json["id"]
```

You do not get back a String. You get a JSON object. If you know it is a string, then cast it.

```
var username = json["id"] as! String

if let username = json["id"] as! String {
    // it is not nil
}
else {
    // it is nil
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks and sorry that I didn't put it in the original question - Is there some way of checking for a nil case scenario here? I mean how can I prevent crashing my app in case json["g_username"] does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it's crash safe

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

if let username = json["id"] as? String {
    defaults.setObject(username, forKey: "username")
}
if let googleUserId = json["g_username"] as? String {
    defaults.setObject(googleUserId, forKey: "googleUserId")
}
if let facebookUserId = json["f_username"] as? String {
    defaults.setObject(facebookUserId, forKey: "facebookUserId")
}

defaults.synchronize()
```

Comment: Thanks, however each of those `as? String` throws me a warning: `Cast from JSON to unrelated type String always fails`, is that fine in this case?

Comment: Can you tell me what's the class of `json` variable?  You need to cast it to NSDictionary.

Comment: Hmm currently it's what my alamofire response brings in, it looks more or less like this: `Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://mywebservice", parameters: par) .response { (request, response, data, error) in
                        if(error == nil){
                            print(data)
                            var json = JSON(data: data!)` this is my json variable. Can I just somehow cast it here safely?

Comment: You need to convert your data into NSDictionary. Check [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) library for easy  parsing.

Comment: I'm already using SwiftyJson, as you can see on their page the last chapter (working with alamofire) is exactly what I'm trying to do :) Now I have to find a way of converting it to the nsdictionary. Can you give me a hint with that? I don't see anything about it on their webpage :(

Comment: Check the "Basic Usage" paragraph of this [link](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/swiftyjson-how-to-handle-json-in-swift/111).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://mywebservice", parameters: par).responseJSON {
    request, response, result in
    switch result {
    case .Success(let data):
        let json = JSON(data: data)
        // ...

    case .Failure(let data, let error):
        print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
    }
}
```